# Ravendb throws IndexCompilationException after new index has been added to code

Tags: ravendb

I have added the simplest of indexes, like this:

```cs
public class MyDocType_ById : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocType>
{
    public MyDocType_ById()
    {
        Map = myDocs => from mine in myDocs
            select new
            {
                Id = mine.Id
            };

        Index(x => x.Id, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

After compiling and hitting my site, I get the following exception:

> [IndexCompilationException: Could not find file 'C:\dev\db\ravendb\CompiledIndexCache\-1836739954.u6DpcVRxqMXarC7cwg26Jg%3d%3d.nodebug.dll'.]

I am creating indexes on my app-startup using

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(MyDocType_ById).Assembly, IoC.Container.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>());
```

In the folder a file is created named `-1836739954.u6DpcVRxqMXarC7cwg26Jg%3d%3d.nodebug.dll.cs` but the dll is not there.

Steps tried:

- ensure correct folder permissions on `C:\dev\db\ravendb\CompiledIndexCache\`
- iisreset + restart ravendb (Windows service)
- renaming the index
- saying for [CURSE] sake out loud in the office

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thorough googling led me to just 1 possible solution found here (where Ayende has also suggested checking folder permissions, ensure no indexing service/antivirus/backup et.c. is touching the folder): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/awh7eV00QNE

OP ended up fixing this by **rebooting his machine**.

This **solved it for me too** (although I surely am curious as to how rebooting differs from restarting all services, et.c...).

I tried to recreate the bug by adding an identical documenttype + index, and this time around it worked correctly right away. Only thing left is hoping this will never reoccur (especially not during e.g. production release...).

Update: this seems to occur occasionally on any of my dev-machines only after waking the system from hibernating (Windows 10), so another solution might be to not hibernate your dev-machine...